# Nextjs 13, running into an issue with value formatter when trying to use tremor for charts in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

```
import { getAuthSession } from "@/lib/auth";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { Card, LineChart, Text, Title } from "@tremor/react";
import Linechart from "./LineChart";

const dollarFormatter = (value: number) =>
  `$ ${Intl.NumberFormat("us").format(value).toString()}`;

const numberFormatter = (value: number) =>
  `${Intl.NumberFormat("us").format(value).toString()}`;

const formatDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  month: "short",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
});

const DashboardNetworth = async () => {
  const session = await getAuthSession();

  const items = await db.item.findMany({
    where: {
      creatorId: session?.user.id,
    },
  });

  // console.log(items);

  const transformedData = items.map((item) => {
    const date = new Date(item.createdAt);
    // @ts-ignore
    item.createdAt = formatDate.format(date);

    return item;
  });

  console.log(transformedData);

  return (
    <Card className="h-[400px]">
      <div className="block sm:flex sm:justify-between">
        <div>
          <Title>Networth</Title>
          <Text>Total networth over time</Text>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <Linechart
        data={transformedData}
        categories={["value"]}
        index={"createdAt"}
        // valueFormatter={numberFormatter}
        color={"teal"}
        curveType={"monotone"}
        maxValue={2500000}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default DashboardNetworth;
```

when value formatter gets passed the error, Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". I am expecting it to format my number values, I have done the obvious and marked the components "use server", I tried it on the parent element too, I even tried to refactor into a new component, no matter what I try value formatter does not want to seem to work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[LineChart is a client component](https://github.com/tremorlabs/tremor/blob/main/src/components/chart-elements/LineChart/LineChart.tsx#L1), so the `valueFormatter` function is going to be called on the client side, but your format function is on the server side, so NextJs try to do some fancy async server action call with your function, when you really just want it to format it on the client side.

To fix this we can create our own client component, and put the formatter function in it, something like:

```
'use client';

import { LineChart } from "@tremor/react";

export interface ChartData{
    ...
}

interface ChartProps {
    chartData: ChartData[];
}

const numberFormatter = (number: number) =>
    `${Intl.NumberFormat("us").format(value).toString()}`;

export default function FormattedChart(props: ChartProps) {
    return <Linechart
        data={props.chartData}
        categories={["value"]}
        index={"createdAt"}
        valueFormatter={numberFormatter}
        color={"teal"}
        curveType={"monotone"}
        maxValue={2500000}
      />
}
```